# Majority time is idle when loading a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

We are developing a web application.

Now the page loading is very slow (>20s). I am using Chrome DevTools Timeline to debug. What I find is that majority of the time is 'Idle'. What is the problem? What is the browser doing when it is 'idle'? Is it because the slow network access speed? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Idle is when it's not doing anything.

Comment: The problem is: why is it not doing anything?

Comment: Because it has nothing to do.

Comment: So it is waiting for response? Why it is not going to load page instead of being idle?

Comment: Hard to know with this little information. How do you know it takes a full 20 sec to load the page? How are you measuring this? What is the page doing on a load? Do you have a lot of resources to load? The `idle` isn't a part of the issue though.

Comment: I see this issue too, and it would be so handy if the profile could provide some clue as to where JS is when idling. Is it siting on a JS line with a `await` or a line that is waiting on a file load or what? Or is all JS happy and not waiting anywhere? A mild puzzle, as I'm using `console.profile()` and `console.profileEnd()` inside one JS function and seeing masses of idle time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could mean your page actually finished loading within ~2.5s. But you may have scripts running that tell your browser to do something every once in a while, for example refresh an ad creative every 5 seconds.

It's hard to know what's actually happening without looking at your site. It'll help if you provide a link.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I had the same issue , think I now know what is the problem:
the reason your page is idle for a long time is, most probably it is asking for a resource that is not reachable! 
in my case, the idle periode ( 30 seconds ) was because somewhere in  my styles.css file I have this line of code :
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
as it could not resolve the url, it takes a very long time for chrome to get over it.

in your chrome DevTools, under Network tab, look which of the resources are not resovled.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs across this and is using Angular...  I had a similar problem with page loads taking 10+ seconds but showing that it was idle in the timeline.  It turns out they were errors that were never shown unless I added  --aot=true to the ng serve command.  It was compiling at run-time and not showing me.  :(